# read single word from listbox vb

Tags: vb.net

I have an order form I created in VB.NET and I have a ListBox that is populated by order. You can double click on the order and it populates the order number in the order form. The problem I'm having is that it populates the TextBox with both the order number and the persons name. How can I use a delimiter to only pull out the order number and not the name also.

```
Imports Business_Objects

Public Class frmSummary
  Private ctrl As Controller
  Dim listID As ArrayList

  Private Sub frmSummary_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ctrl = CType(MdiParent, frmMain).ctrl
    Dim list As ArrayList
    list = ctrl.GetOrders
    Dim order As Business_Objects.Order
    For Each order In list
      lstOrders.Items.Add(order.ID & "," & " " & order.Server)
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub lstOrders_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.DoubleClick
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    If lstOrders.Text <> "" Then
      result = True
      Dim frm As New OrderForm
      frm.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
      frm.Show()
      frm.txtOrderNo.Text = lstOrders.Text
      frm.btnFetch.PerformClick()
    Else
      MessageBox.Show("there are no orders here to click")
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    lstOrders.Items.Clear()
    ctrl = CType(MdiParent, frmMain).ctrl
    Dim list As ArrayList
    list = ctrl.GetOrders
    Dim order As Business_Objects.Order
    For Each order In list
      lstOrders.Items.Add(order.ID & " " & order.Server)
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How are you storing the data? Text file? 
Generally, your data will already be delimited by something. This paragraph for example could be read as delimited by spaces, so string array = paragraph.split(" ") could be used to populate whatever with the index of 0 to get the first entry in the paragraph.

Comment: its stored in visual studios sql compact database

Comment: Best thing to do is to not save the name and order as one attribute in your table. It sounds like you are committing all the data as a single record? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your data is being stored as a single field, or something like:

```
4322305 John Smith Carrots $3.00
845825 Sam White Oranges $1.25
```

Then you can read each record as a string, and then use split that into an array based on " " as your delimiter.

The code would look something like:

```
dim myArray as string() = myLongTextRecord.Split(" ")
```

And in that format,

```
textBoxName.Text = myArray[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You could use the split function, but another approach would be to add the Order object directly to the listbox and not text.

```
Private Sub frmSummary_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ctrl = CType(MdiParent, frmMain).ctrl
    Dim list As ArrayList
    list = ctrl.GetOrders
    Dim order As Business_Objects.Order
    For Each order In list
      lstOrders.Items.Add(order)
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub lstOrders_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.DoubleClick
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    If lstOrders.Text <> "" Then
      result = True
      Dim frm As New OrderForm
      frm.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
      frm.Show()
      frm.txtOrderNo.Text = DirectCast(lstOrders.SelectedItem, Order).ID.ToString
      frm.btnFetch.PerformClick()
    Else
      MessageBox.Show("there are no orders here to click")
    End If
  End Sub
```

You'll need to go into the Order object and override the .ToString function so that the text in the Listbox displays whatever value you want (ie. `Return ID & "," & " " & Server`)